# Android activity overlay parentactivity

Tags: android

I have a parent activity with one top bar with some buttons, onloading the the parent activity i am trying to load child activity above parent activity as Dialog using

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

code. and its loading up fine, but i wanted to click the button on the parent tababr buttons to change the view in the child activity. Sicnce the child activity loading as a dialog theme the parent activity buttons are not active. IS there any way to do it? so that i can access the parent activity button after loading child activity as Dialog? Please give some solutions.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this if they are sitting in two different activities..

But there is way if both the views are in a single activity.

- You set the acitivity to the root view using the `setContentView`
- Create a second view which would have been your new activity.
- Set the `LayoutParams` for this view which defines the view boundaries
- Add the second view to the first view.

Now you should be able to use the buttons that are visible in the first view even when the second view is shown..

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, So your saying Single activity with One view right? Overlaying view above the Current activity. Is that right?